# mongodb compass aggregation $match range with dynamic dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

i am trying to build an aggregation pipeline in mongodb compass. i'm using $match to look for documents within a date range. i want the date range to always be the "current week".

this works:

```
 $match: {
    CREATED_ON: {
      $gte: ISODate('2019-09-01'),
      $lt: ISODate('2019-09-07')
    }
  }
```

but i need it to be like this:

```
  $match: {
    CREATED_ON: {
      $gte: *first day of current week*,
      $lt: *last day of current week*
    }
  }
```

how do i do this in a compass agg pipeline?

Comment: Hi, MongoDB 4.2 includes a `$$NOW` variable, which returns the current time as an ISODate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to dynamically match the current date within Mongo aggregation framework.

In your server-side app, you would have to dynamically compute the start-date and end-date, and then pass that into your $match.

Below is an example function for getting the beginning and end dates of the current week (assuming beginning=Sunday and end=Saturday).

```js
const SUNDAY_DAY_NUMBER = 0;
const SATURDAY_DAY_NUMBER = 6;

/**
 * @example
 * const dateQuery = getDateQueryForCurrentWeek();
 * const matchObject = { CREATED_ON: dateQuery };
 * const findResult = db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([{ $match: matchObject }]).toArray();
 */
const getDateQueryForCurrentWeek = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const numDaysToBeginningOfWeek = SUNDAY_DAY_NUMBER - now.getDay();
  const numDaysToEndOfWeek = SATURDAY_DAY_NUMBER - now.getDay();

  const firstDayOfCurrentWeek = new Date(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate() + numDaysToBeginningOfWeek,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  );
  const lastDayOfCurrentWeek = new Date(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate() + numDaysToEndOfWeek,
    24,
    0,
    0,
    -1
  );

  const query = {
    $gte: firstDayOfCurrentWeek,
    $lte: lastDayOfCurrentWeek
  };

  return query;
};
```

Comment: Hi, MongoDB 4.2 includes a `$$NOW` variable, which returns the current time as an ISODate.

Comment: this is a great idea @christian Thank you